# Margin-Top does not apply in div elemt

Tags: html, css, overflow

So I was experimenting with a simple layout. It is basicaly an interview layout with lots of pictures.

this is the basic concept I am following:

-intro

-photos

-interview

I am putting a margin-top to the `<div id="interview">` but it doesnt work.Why? There is a problem with the structure of my layout I think.(if you click on inspect element in chrome)

How to fix that? The link: http://mysecretathens.gr/kulte_test/osterman.html

Comment: Impossible to determine question from its contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clean way to fix this would be to add "overflow: hidden" to the photos element.

```
#photos {overflow:hidden;}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because you've not cleared the floating elements, just clear the floats before you declare `<div id="interview">` like this and than use `margin-top: /* Whatever px */`

```
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div id="interview">
```

And looking at your website, you are using heavy images on landing page which will annoy any user running low on bandwidth, I would suggest you to take a look at `lazy loading`

Comment: Thanks man, lazy loading is also just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It “does not work”, because all the images above are floated – and therefor do not span up the height of their parent element.

Add `overflow:hidden` to your `#photos` div, so that it contains all its images and does not have them floating out of it – then a margin-top on the following element will work as expected.